# Is it possible to swap two elements in a collection?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, immutability

Let an immutable collection (e.g. `Seq`) ; I would want to swap some elements ("some" = if some condition is verified).

Conceptually, there are 2 cases :

1. Swapping is done on a copy of the original collection, thus it doesn't depend on precedent swaps.
2. Swapping is done on a copy of the original collection - **copy that is being used for swapping** - thus it depends on precedent swaps.

The first case is the simplest one. Indeed, we need `map`, verify the condition for the processed element, and we replace it by another : `my_collection.map(current_element => { if(...) { another_element } else { current_element }})`. NB : other conditions may be used, depending on the condition determining each swap.

The last case is more difficult : I need to work on the current state of the collection. **Do you know if it's possible ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only realistic method is to apply case 1 repeatedly until there are no more swaps to be applied.

You first need to modify case 1 to use a `foldLeft` operation on the original collection that returns a tuple containing the new collection and a `boolean` indicating whether any swaps were performed.

You then wrap this in a recursive function that applies this operation and then returns the new collection if no swaps happened, or recursively calls itself with the new collection if at least one swap happened.

You may also need to check for infinite recursion in case the "swap" operation changes the collection back to one of the previous values.